# KSOAP2 Android - Create SOAP Request with complex queries

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to create following SOAP Request with KSOAP2 Android

**Expected -**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <Rootnow xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <Category xmlns:a="http://aboutsoap.com/anything" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3schools.org/2014/instance">
        <a:CategoryOne>
           <a:Child1>Hello</a:Child1>
           <a:Child2>Hello</a:Child2>
           <a:Child3>true</a:Child3>
           <a:Child4>Hello</a:Child4>
        </a:CategoryOne>
        <a:CategoryTwo>Hello</a:CategoryTwo>
        <a:CategoryThree>HelloWorld</a:CategoryThree>
        <a:CategoryFour i:nil="true" />
     </Category>
   </Rootnow>
  </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

I have tried with creating PropertyInfo classes and SoapObjects and able to get following response

**Actual -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <Rootnow xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <n0:Category xmlns:n0="http://aboutsoap.com/anything">
        <n0:CategoryOne>
           <n0:Child1>Hello</n0:Child1>
           <n0:Child2>Hello</n0:Child2>
           <n0:Child3>true</n0:Child3>
           <n0:Child4>Hello</n0:Child4>
        </n0:CategoryOne>
        <n0:CategoryTwo>Hello</n0:CategoryTwo>
        <n0:CategoryThree>HelloWorld</n0:CategoryThree>
        <n0:CategoryFour i:nil="true" />
     </n0:Category>
   </Rootnow>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here I am getting prefix to Category and only one namespace shown to it
Using KSOAP2 how can I create expected SOAP request?

One silly question - I am getting prefix as **n0**. can I use **a** as prefix? or it doesn't make any difference to request

**Edited**
I am just rephrasing my question. How can I create SOAP Object which is having name and two namespaces and no prefix attached?

e.g.

```
       <Category xmlns:a="http://aboutsoap.com/anything" 
       xmlns:i="http://www.w3schools.org/2014/instance">
```

and How can I provide this namespace **xmlns:a="http://aboutsoap.com/anything** to its node child

Comment: There are lots of similar question in SO.
Check [this][1] link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269731/ksoap2-how-to-change-prefixes

Comment: Hi MobiDev I have gone through many SO questions and succeeded to build above response. I looking for achieving exact response. Please check edited part